# Android BroadcastReceiver onReceive() called twice on android 4.0

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I faced to one problem on android 4.0.3 (on 4.1.2 it works fine).
I have in my Activity BroadcastReceiver. When I send a broadcast, method onReceive() called always twice. Please give me any suggestions about BroadcastReceiver differences on 4.0 and 4.1

```
private final GcmBroadcastReceiver gcmReceiver = new GcmBroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && action.equals(MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION)) {
            Log.d("tag", intent.getStringExtra("alert"));
            }
        }
    };

};


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(gcmReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerGcmReceiver();
}

private void registerGcmReceiver() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
    filter.setPriority(2);
    filter.addCategory("com.android.mypackage");
    registerReceiver(gcmReceiver, filter);
}
```

Comment: I was also having the same problem but the fault must be on our side, I was calling some method twice resulting in receiving intent twice. I would suggest to debug your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: there isn't a difference. The `BroadcastReceiver` class for both is from Android 2.3.2 r1.

I've had a similar problem, but for me it was with an HTC Desire HD with Android 2.3.5 on it - the notifications from GCM would always get received twice. I didn't manage to find the root of the problem, but there is a workaround. You can generate a unique ID for each notification in the server and send it along with the actual data. Then, in your receiver, you can update a mapping of unique ID to notification data, and if there is already data for the given ID, just ignore it.

I probably didn't make that very clear, so here's an example:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("notificationID");
    if (myMap.get(id) != null)
        return;

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && action.equals(MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION)) {
        Log.d("tag", intent.getStringExtra("alert"));
        myMap.put(id, *any value you need*);
    }
}
```

If you don't need to store additional data, you can use a HashSet instead of a Map and just check if it contains the ID.

Comment: btw I have such problem on HTC too (HTC ONE X)

Comment: what is myMap identifier

Comment: `myMap` is any Java `Map`, e.g. a `HashMap`

Comment: This answer may be misleading. I almost took it as true, until I saw Mercury's answer.

Comment: I agree. IIRC this was a device- and OS-specific issue in my case, and _not_ something caused by registering twice. Mercury's answer helps with a more common issue that looks very similar.

Answer (score 45):

Usually onReceive is being called twice since people are registering the broadcast in **2 locations**,
**Most likely you are registering in your onCreate  and  in your onResume.**
(Choose one spot to register).


Although you might have done it probably a dozen of times - it is always recommended to take another glance at the [Activity Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc).

Comment: It's a brilliant advice. Thanks @Mercury .

Comment: Simple and brilliant answer. +1

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, I had indeed registered it twice: in manifest and by code.

Comment: For me, I was only registering it in one place, but it would get registered twice because my onResume() was getting called a second time after a dialog.

Comment: Sometimes you register in onResume()/onStart() but unregister in onDestroy(). And it's highly possible that onResume()/onStart() called multiple times.Therefore multiple firings

Answer (score 25):

I had same issue.

`onReceive()` gets called twice because i was registering Broadcast receiver twice. One in my activity's `onCreate()` and another in `manifest`.

I remove broadcast receiver registration from `onCreate()` and it's working fine. Register your broadcast receiver in only one of them.

There are two ways to do this:

- Statically in the manifest file.
- Dynamically in the code.

Which method (static or dynamic) to use when depends completely upon what you’re trying to do. Basically when you want to do some changes right on the screen (home screen, launcher, status bar, etc.) by showing up some notification or some indicator in the status bar by listening to system wide events or maybe those sent by other apps, then it make sense to use statically registered broadcast receivers. Whereas based on similar events you want to do changes right in your app when the user is using it or maybe it’s put in the background, then it makes sense to use dynamically registered receivers which’ll last till the registering components are destroyed.

For more info:
http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/

Answer (score 8):

Initialize `BroadcastReciver` in `onStart()`. This fixed my problem.

Comment: Question is..why.. why does it do that in the first place... crappy android

Comment: @Martin Kovachev - a man after my own heart

Answer (score 2):

You can also implement it by setting a boolean flag, when you enter to `onReceive()` function

Answer (score 2):

For ***Xamarin*** developers:

I had a similar problem and for me it was because I registered the broadcast receiver in two places, one somewhere in my codes:

```
Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("MY_INTENT_ACTION"));
```

And the other via Attributes:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "MY_INTENT_ACTION" })]
public class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    }
}
```

I removed Attributes and the problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the correct way to determine if Wifi has connected or disconnected.

The onReceive() method in the BroadcastReceiver:Just put a Simple checking(Its a logic implemented by SharedPreferences):

```
package com.example.broadcasttest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

boolean isInternetPresent = false;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
            .getPackageName();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;


    if(packageName.equals("com.example.broadcasttest") && taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().toString().equals("com.example.broadcasttest.MainActivity"))
    {

        //          SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("FLAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //          String check=sharedPreferences.getString("check","");

        ConnectionDetector  cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("FLAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String check=sharedPreferences.getString("check","");
            if(check.equals("chkd1")){
                Log.d("activity name", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName()+"   Package Name :  "+componentInfo.getPackageName());


                String abc = context.getClass().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, "hiiii "+abc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("ghorar kochu", "checking:");
                MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

                m.abc(context);
            }
            else if(check.equals("chkd"))
            {
                Log.e("Thanks For the checking", "checking:"+check);
            }
        }
        else if (!isInternetPresent) {
                 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=context.getSharedPreferences("FLAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sharedPreferences1.edit();
            editor1.putString("check","chkd1");
            editor1.commit();
        }

    }




}



}
```

This is actual receiver class.Now coming to the main activity.

```
package com.example.broadcasttest;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=getSharedPreferences("FLAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sharedPreferences1.edit();
        editor1.putString("check","chkd1");
        editor1.commit();
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
    public void abc(Context context){
        try{
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=context.getSharedPreferences("FLAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sharedPreferences1.edit();
        editor1.putString("check","chkd");
        editor1.commit();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new JsonForTimeLineList().execute();
        }

    class JsonForTimeLineList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private String msg = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //  pDialog.show();


        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void  resultaaa) {


            Log.e("hi", "helo");


        }

    }

    }
```

This code only works when your app is onresume state and when it is in MainActivity.

Here is my ConnectionDetector class.Through which i am checking the connection of wifi.

```
package com.example.broadcasttest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

     private Context _context;

        public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
            this._context = context;
        }

        public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
              if (connectivity != null) 
              {
                  NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                  if (info != null) 
                      for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                          if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                          {
                              return true;
                          }

              }
              return false;
        }


}
```

And here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcasttest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.CustomReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my log when i am enable the wifi.

```
11-19 20:13:11.474: D/activity name(25417): CURRENT Activity ::com.example.broadcasttest.MainActivity   Package Name :  com.example.broadcasttest
11-19 20:13:11.481: E/ghorar kochu(25417): checking:
11-19 20:13:11.542: E/hi(25417): helo
11-19 20:13:11.573: V/RenderScript(25417): Application requested CPU execution
11-19 20:13:11.580: V/RenderScript(25417): 0xb90a7850 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
11-19 20:13:17.158: E/Thanks For the checking(25417): checking:chkd
```

If you have any query just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I was calling `sendBroadcast(intent)` multiple times in my **Service class**

**Removing one of them** fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason for this issue.

Basically when we register the receiver for BLUETOOTH_STATE_CHANGE then if we are **Turning ON** the bluetooth then its onReceive() method will call twice for the following two Bluetooth States:

STATE 1: STATE_TURNING_ON
Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is turning on.

STATE 2: STATE_ON
Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is on, and ready for use.

Same while **Turing OFF** the bluetooth then its onReceive() method will again call twice for the following two Bluetooth States:

STATE 1: STATE_TURNING_OFF
Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is turning off.

STATE 2: STATE_OFF
Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is off.

So basically we can handle this situation in the following way:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {

            // When Bluetooth adapter is on, and ready for use
            //DO YOUR CODE HERE FOR "BLUETOOTH ON" CASE


        }
        else if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {

            //When local Bluetooth adapter is off
            //DO YOUR CODE HERE FOR "BLUETOOTH OFF" CASE

        }

    }
}
```

After looking to your code(@girlOnSledge), it seems that if you will follow the above procedure, your code will also work fine in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, but my `BroadcastReceiver` was static because I wanted to use it as an inner class, what I did was to register the receiver (in order to create the static instance), then unregister the same receiver, that made it be called once which is by the `AlarmManager` timer, ofcourse code is always much explanatory :

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    Log.d("EX", "Alarm SET !!");

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.START_ALARM");
    IntentFilter myIf = new IntentFilter("com.example.START_ALARM");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    myBroadcastReceiver mbr = new myBroadcastReceiver();
    // ****Here goes the trick.****
    context.registerReceiver(mbr, myIf);
    context.unregisterReceiver(mbr);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(70);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(70), sender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem and I found a solution that wasn't mentioned in any of the existed answers, so I would like to share it.

I register the BroadcastReceiver just once in *onCreate*

However, I was registering it like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), mStatusIntentFilter);
```

In other words, I was **constructing** the boradcastReceiver instance inside the *registerReceiver* call.

But when I construct the BroadcastReceiver in **a separate statement** the problem was solved. Like this:

```
MyBroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver , mStatusIntentFilter);
```

Very weird workaround, maybe it's a bug that will be fixed later.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed this issue by using a **static** value.

Please find my code below.

**My Activity**

```
private static Snackbar mSnackbar;
private NetworkChangeReceiver mNetworkChangeReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceivers();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unRegisterReceivers();
}
private void registerReceivers() {
    mNetworkChangeReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver() {
        @Override
        protected void onNetworkChange(boolean status) {
            if (!status) {
                if (mSnackbar == null) {
                    mSnackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(drawer, R.string.no_internet, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                            .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                }
                            });
                    mSnackbar.show();
                }
            } else {
                if (mSnackbar != null) {
                    mSnackbar.dismiss();
                    mSnackbar = null;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter nwStateChangeFilter = new IntentFilter();
    nwStateChangeFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    nwStateChangeFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver, nwStateChangeFilter);
}
private void unRegisterReceivers() {
    unregisterReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver);
}
```

**NetworkChangeReceiver.Class**

```
public abstract class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                    // connected to wifi
                    onNetworkChange(true);
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
                    onNetworkChange(true);
                } else {
                    // not connected to the internet
                    onNetworkChange(false);
                }
        } else {
            // not connected to the internet
            onNetworkChange(false);
        }
    }
    protected abstract void onNetworkChange(boolean status);
}
```

Comment: using static field is likely a workaround, not a solution. Moreover, this approach isn't covered by unit tests.

Comment: Yes, its a workaround and not a solution for this issue.

Comment: Workaround ... solution ..bugfix ... whatever.  As long as it works CONSISTENTLY (and by that I mean after the tsunami of upgrades from Google/Android/Microsoft/Uncle Tom Cobbleigh and all) AND it is understood by those who come after you, then its VALID.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it would be best to register the receiver after you have overridden the `BroadcastReceiver` and before starting the intent from which you want to receive data.(Otherwise it may throw a `NullPointerException`.
Unregister the reciever in `onStop()` rather than in `onPause()`.

I have noticed that unregistering the receiver in the `onPause()` creates problems if you have services or background tasks to be executed, which will pause the activity and hence unregister your Broadcast Receiver. (This will result in multiple calls to the `onRecieve()` method, i.e. each time the receiver is re-registered.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I decorated the broadcast class with `[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]` and at the same time registered it in `OnResume`. I fixed it by commenting out `//[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid getting this problem, If you register your broadcast receiver from custom Application class. This will make sure that your broadcast receiver will be registered only once for the entire application life cycle.