# Android BroadcastReceiver onReceive() called twice on android 5.1.1 even after one register

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I Could not figure out what is wrong with below code. I also checked about registering receiver twice. But that's also not the case. or may be I am missing something.
Could any please help. I really need it. :(

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * 
 * @author Bharat
 *
 */
public class CallNotifierService extends Service 
{
    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private CallBr br_call;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.br_call);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;
        public boolean answered = false;
        public boolean outgoing = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) 
            {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) 
                {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) 
                    {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) 
                    {
                        if (wasRinging == true) 
                        {
                            answered = true;
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Answered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) 
                    {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            } 
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) 
            {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) 
                {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing Call : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    outgoing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the activity I am calling it from

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.roaming);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallNotifierService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
.
.
.
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ind.cosmos.main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> -->
        <activity
            android:name="ind.cosmos.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="ind.cosmos.callRecord.CallNotifierService" />
    </application>
```

Comment: For which of the two actions, is it being called twice?

Comment: That may be because the system would be sending it twice. Its actually true when you are listening broadcasts for calls or contacts .

Comment: its Toast.makeText(...) twice everytime a call comes or I dial

Comment: i haven't searched on that much . but which action's broadcast you are getting twice phone state or outgoing call ?

Comment: @Arslan all the Toast ... ie. 2 "Incomeing Call", 2 "Outgoing Call", 2 "Answered", 2 "Disconnected".

Comment: Are you sure you are registering this just in your service ? if yes then check if your onStartCommand is being called twice?

Comment: yes.. I put this log. Log.i("Registerd Once",this.br_call.toString()); and this is printing only once while Toast is visible twice. ===LOG===> 02-18 17:12:12.485: I/Registerd Once(23513): ind.cosmos.callRecord.CallNotifierService$CallBr@2eeef552

Comment: I am getting a similar problem when pairing with a Bluetooth device. The BroadcastReceiver is getting called twice with the message 'pairing complete'.

Comment: @ Brian .... Just check ..you should not be registering it 2 places . it should be either Mainfest or class ... but not both.

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563020/7758211

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually .. there is nothing wrong with the code. its System who triggers this. some time its 2 times.. other times it touches 4 times.

So the best we can do it handle it in the code itself.

Answer (score 7):

As Bharat said it's better so handle it in code. Below is a trick to do so, found [here](http://mmarvick.github.io/blog/blog/lollipop-multiple-broadcastreceiver-call-state/), thanks to Michael Marvick who has given detail description as well.

```
     public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static final String TAG = "PHONE STATE";
        private static String mLastState;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if (!state.equals(mLastState)) {
                mLastState = state;
                Log.e(TAG, state);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But what if state is Incoming sms this code will fail.

Comment: if the user wants to perform an action twice say for example fast forward audio for 30 seconds, the second fast forward will not work because the last state is same as current state.

Comment: In that case you may pass another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior, and there is no issue in your code. android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE can be received few times, but Intent's bundle is always different, for example:

```
D/App(2001): Bundle{ state => OFFHOOK; subscription => 1; }Bundle
D/App(2001): Bundle{ incoming_number => 555555555; state => OFFHOOK; subscription => 9223372036854775807; }Bundle
```